# Preserve ordering of selectizeInput selections in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-reactivity

Steps to replicate my problem:

1. Run app
2. Select "D" in Choice 2
3. Remove "C" in Choice 1
4. In Choice 1, drag "B" in front of "A"

Choice 1 has pre-selected options, while Choice 2 is blank by default.

When a selection is made in Choice 1, that option is removed in the drop down list for Choice 2.

I would like to be able to order my selections, but they always go back to the original order. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)

# UI ----------
ui <- fluidPage(
        uiOutput("Select1"),
        uiOutput("Select2"))

# Server -------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals <- reactiveValues(sel1 = character(),
                        sel2 = character())

observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    vals$sel1 = input$Select1
})

observeEvent(input$Select2, {
     vals$sel2 = input$Select2
})

  output$Select1 <- renderUI({

    letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    selected = c("A", "B", "C")

    if (length(vals$sel1) != 0 && vals$sel1 %in% letters) {
      selected = vals$sel1
    }

    selectizeInput('Select1', label = "Choice 1:",
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   choices = letters[!letters %in% input$Select2],
                   selected = selected,
                   options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))

  })

  output$Select2 <- renderUI({

    letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    selected <- NULL

    if (length(vals$sel2) != 0 && vals$sel2 %in% letters) {
      selected = vals$sel2
    }

    selectizeInput('Select2', label = "choice 2:",
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   choices = letters[!letters %in% input$Select1],
                   selected = selected,
                   options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Using isolate() around selected doesn't work. I was able to get the ordering to work with the following code, but then lost the ability to preserve my selections.

```
observeEvent(input$Select1, {
  # Allows reordering of columns
  if (!all(vals$sel1 %in% input$Select1)) {
    vals$sel1 = input$Select1
  }
})

observeEvent(input$Select2, {
  # Allows reordering of columns
  if (!all(vals$sel2 %in% input$Select2)) {
    vals$sel2 = input$Select2
  }
})
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are recreating the UI element every time the input selects which causes the selections to be sorted. I personally would probably consider using `updateSelectizeInput` because rendering them dynamically on the server side sort of undermines the point of selectize.

That being said, you can add a `req` statement to your code to prevent them from the dynamic UI from re-rendering unless the values are actually changed (or there are none to cover initial rendering)

```
  output$Select1 <- renderUI({
    
    req(!all(vals$sel1 %in% input$Select1) | is.null(input$Select1), cancelOutput = TRUE)
    
    letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
     ...<<other code>>...
    
  })
  
  output$Select2 <- renderUI({
    
    req(!all(vals$sel2 %in% input$Select2) | is.null(input$Select1), cancelOutput = TRUE)
    
    letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    
    ...<<other code>>...
    
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! The `req()` helps retain my UI elements. Are you suggesting to use `updateSelectizeInput` over `req()` or use them together?

Comment: Use them together. Instead of using `renderUI`, create and observer which first uses the `req` check and then `updateSelectizeInput` if necessary. This will update the choices instead of recreating the entire UI section

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `orderInput()` from `shinyjqui` package might be useful in your case.  Please note that if in your use case you have too many choices in select3, you may need to reconsider.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

### UI ----------
ui <- fluidPage(

  orderInput(inputId = 'select1', 'Choice 1: ', items = LETTERS[1:3], connect = c("select3", "select2")),
  orderInput(inputId = 'select2', 'Choice 2: ', items = NULL, connect = c("select1", "select3"), placeholder = 'Drag item here...'),
  orderInput(inputId = 'select3', 'Choose items', items = LETTERS[4:7], connect = c("select1", "select2")),
  verbatimTextOutput("t1")

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$t1 <- renderPrint({input$select1})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]